# I have obtained vignette sticker from OFII. How long can I stay in India?

Tags: france, indian-citizens, india

I arrived to France from India on a long stay visa with my wife and child as dependents. I have obtained a vignette sticker from OFII (Office français de l'immigration et l'intégration - French bureau for immigration and integration) for myself and my wife. I have also obtained a DCEM (document de circulation pour étranger mineur - a residence permit for minors) for my child. How long can my wife and child stay in India without effecting the vignette sticker? And I am not sure if it is constrained and therefore would like to confirm.

Comment: Can you please expand the acronyms "OFII" and "DCEM"?